# Apache server search for directory instead of route

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a simple php routing system and use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for routing.
a sample one :

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch ($url) {
    case '':
    case '/';
        require 'view/home.php';
        break;
    case '/admin';
        require 'admin/home.php';
        break;
}
```

problem is when there is `admin` subfolder in public_html, routing system fails and Apache tries to open admin directory and change `domain.com/admin` to `domain.com/admin/`.

here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your second RewriteCond explicitly checks that the requested path does _not_ match an existing directory, and only lets the rewrite proceed if that was not the case.

Comment: @CBroe Deleting second condition didn't change anything. It still redirect /admin to /admin/

Comment: Yes, that part would be `mod_dir`'s doing. To disable that, use the [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive. (But pay attention to the potential security issue the documentation warns about.)

Comment: @CBroe Please post answers as "answers", rather than answers in "comments".

Comment: @CBroe i updated htaccess and added `DirectorySlash Off` , Its is not working either

Comment: Did you clear your browser history, or tested in a private window, to make sure this isn't just the cache fooling you? If so - then please give a _proper_ explanation of what you actually want to achieve, and _how_ exactly it is "not working."

Comment: (If you want `/admin` rewritten to your index.php, then that second RewriteCond still needs to go, that the case now?)

Comment: @CBroe well , in this website `https://rezamnk.ir/album` when I put slash in the end, local cdns all trying to find /album/ directory and search cdn routing from there and they woun't find them, so I have to disable Apache default directory routing to use query strings to route. I tried clearing my cashe (hard reloaded and used private window too) and delete second condition too

Comment: No, what you should do instead, is refer to your assets with relative paths starting with a leading slash, so that they refer to the web root. Then it doesn't matter any more, whether the address of the main document that was embedding them was `/album` or`/album/`.

Comment: You mean `https://rezamnk.ir/assets/....` or `/home/username/domainname/...` ? so there is no way this option i want works ?

Comment: No, I mean `/assets/...`

Comment: using slashes routes from root : / => /root